# Javascript Ternary Operator in Sequence

Tags: javascript

I got the code below from a Javascript Library:

```
function func_1()
{
    if ( null == decimal ) 
    {
        return dPR || (dpr(2) ? 2 : dpr(1.5) ? 1.5 : dpr(1) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

I'm particularly interested in the code inside the `if` statement.

How else can I write this so that it's easier to read?! As it is now I can't understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: Give meaningful names to the constants and don't use some random acronyms.

Comment: Post all your code. I believe it is missing some definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's equivalent to:

```
if (dPR) {
    return dPR;
} else {
    if (dpr(2)) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        if (dpr(1.5)) {
            return 1.5;
        } else {
            if (dpr(1)) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dPr) {
    return dPr;
} 
else {
    if (dpr(2))
        return 2
    else if (dpr(1.5))
        return 1.5;
    else if (dpr(1))
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. This is actually closer to what my brain wants to process as regards the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( decimal == null ) {

    if ( dPR ) {

        return dPR;

    } else {

        if ( dpr(2) ) {

            return 2;

        } else if ( dpr(1.5) ) {

            return 1.5;

        } else if ( dpr(1) ) {

            return 1;

        } else return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: This is not correct, you do have a double else-branch in your code.